# Android: Observing Room DB through LiveData & ViewModel in Activity

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have created a basic example in which, an activity is observing room DB through LiveData. For more information, please check the following code:

```
    @Dao
    interface NoteDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM note ORDER BY date_created DESC")
        fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Note>>
    }

    // Repository
    class ReadersRepository(private val context: Context) {
        private val appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .build()
        fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>> {
            return appDatabase.getNoteDao().getAll()
        }
    }

    // ViewModel   
    class AllNotesViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
        private val repository = ReadersRepository(application)
        internal var allNotesLiveData: LiveData<List<Note>> = repository.getAllNotes()
    }

    // Activity
    class MainActivity : BaseActivity<AllNotesViewModel>() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

            viewModel.allNotesLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
                adapter.setData(it)
            })
        }
    }
```

So, here is the thing. It is working fine. Any update on DB from the background happens then Activity gets a callback.

However, Why is it not throwing any error while accessing (observing) DB on MainThread?

Did I implement in the correct way?
What am I missing in this?

Comment: Eventually, you're not observing db directly. Now after `LiveData` implementation you're observing live data which in case getting updates off the main thread from Room db. That's the case, if you omit `LiveData` entirely from this implementation you'll get that error definitely.

Comment: If you are not using LiveData then you should handle it on your worker thread and if you do it on the main thread it will definitely crash, However, if you use Room & Live Data, room generates all the code to update the LiveData when a database is updated, later code runs the query asynchronously on a background thread when needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the default behavior of the Room. By default, it will query on the background thread for those functions whose return-type is `LiveData`

> Room generates all the necessary code to update the LiveData object
>   when a database is updated. The generated code runs the query
>   asynchronously on a background thread when needed. This pattern is
>   useful for keeping the data displayed in a UI in sync with the data
>   stored in a database.

[More Info](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Perfect Answer.